# SWIFT: First Time Input / Edit Mode, one screen or two screens?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I've create the following screen which takes 4 inputs when the user creates an account and 'Submits' for the first time.

[image]

After they submit once, the screen should go to "edit mode'.  My question is, is it more effective to create two view controllers (one for initial input, and the other for edit mode), or just one view controller.  If the latter, does anyone have any examples or tutorials? I'm positive that I'm not the first one to attempt this. Thanks!

Comment: "is it more effective to create two view controllers" What does "more effective" even _mean_? And what _is_ "edit mode"? The same screen (four labels and submit button) or something different?

Comment: @matt, my apologies for not explaining this better.  "EffectIve" means "which way is the best practice?".   The two screens will be the same, except that on the "Edit" screen, the "Submit" button will be an "Edit" button, and until it's pressed, the text fields will not be editable (they will display the numbers inputed when the user first entered their inputs).

Comment: In that case it is much simpler and better to change the button title and the editability of the text fields, in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to do here is toggle the button's title and the editability of the text fields, so it is simplest (and best) to do that in place, in the same view and the same view controller. You are merely changing *features* of this view, not swapping out this view for another world of interface.